# Unable to get response with Retrofit Coroutine api call

Tags: android, retrofit2, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to get response into live data from api, but request is not getting called with this code.

```
class AuthActivityViewModel : ViewModel() {

    var authResp: LiveData<ObjAuthResp> = MutableLiveData()

    val repository = BaseRepository()

    fun login(username: String, password: String) {
        authResp = liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {
          val resp = repository.login(username, password)
            emit(resp)
        }
    }
}
```

but it works with this code.

```
class AuthActivityViewModel : ViewModel() {

    val repository = BaseRepository()

    var authResp = liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val resp = repository.login(username, password)
            emit(resp)
    }    

}
```

API service

```
@POST("profile/pub/auth/login")
suspend fun login(@Body authReqBody : ObjAuthReqBody): ObjAuthResp
```

BaseRepository

```
open class BaseRepository {

    suspend fun login(username:String,password:String) = service.login(ObjAuthReqBody( username, password))   
}
```

Calling from activity

```
   btn_login.setOnClickListener {
    viewModel.login(edt_username.text.toString(), 
    edt_password.text.toString())
    }
```

Comment: Show us your Repository code

Comment: I think it's because you're not calling your login function in the ViewModel from anywhere

Comment: trust me im calling)

Comment: What's your proof that it isn't getting called? Do you have some log statements? Put a log statement into the click listener, for example, and one inside the `login` function, and post that code.

Comment: I appreciate that you spent your time on this case, but i did debug my code before posting the problem here and debugger reached the line authResp = liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {...  but retrofit did not make a call to the api, I have attached HttpLoggingInterceptor to my Retrofit, otherwise i'd get the calling logs from it, which i did in my case 1, which worked without login function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question,

the problem was in line `authResp = liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {...` this was creating new LiveData while the old observers where observing the initial `var authResp: LiveData<ObjAuthResp> = MutableLiveData()`. So, as there is no Observers listening to the newly created `LiveData` the call is not even being made.

This code is working

```
  var authResp = MutableLiveData<ObjAuthResp>()

 fun login(username: String, password: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                val resp = repository.login(username, password)
                authResp.postValue( resp)

            }
        }
    }
```